# Flash wmode="transparent" shows weird colors and outlines in Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, wmode

Maybe it was a recent FF update, but at the end of this flash intro, lots of random red and green colors show up.

http://incitoconsultants.com/test/index.php

Comment: looks fine here in ff 3.5.5 flash 10 windows vista x64.

Answer (score 0):

Your embed method is not truly cross browser nor standards compliant.  You should be using the swfobject method: http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: I updated my code with the swfobject method, but still get the same issue.

Comment: Try dropping down you swf Flash version to 9: FF3 seems to be budded with wmode transparent:  

http://inspiredrobot.com/blog/2009/03/05/transparent-wmode-crashes-browser-in-flash-10-with-3d-filters-and-simplebuttons/

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-983

Otherwise, you could try and edit the technique you are using for that animated "wave".  I would bet that filters or blend mode could be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

In flash, I changed one of my background elements from 80% Alpha to 100%, and that seemed to fix it. I don't have any clue why.